# saving a file outside of my application bundel in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i want to save a file outside of my application bundle as a backup of database so that when user reinstall my app or my app crashes he can backup his data from that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple already does this, with iTunes.

What you are asking is technically against apple's policy, unless you store it off site, on a server (which you could easily do)

If you have a lot of applications, I'm not aware of the policy, but perhaps you could make an app to back up your other app's data.

Comment: first thanks for ur response. second can my any second application can access my app database. and can we acces any thing like pictures or movies outside my app bundle.

Comment: No problem, I'm sorry i'm not more help, I'm not familiar with the exact protocol when it comes to outside access, I believe you can access the main photo database, so sharing stuff between apps that way is fine, however I would bet that you're not supposed to access anything outside your sandbox at all. If i remember correctly. I'm sorry!